# Cómo corregir este error creando esta GUI?

Tags: mysql, python, tkinter

En resumen, soy un novato que tiene una idea para una GUI y he estado viendo varios vídeos y demás, y llevo varios días atascado en lo mismo buscando info por foros etc y nada. He linkado (supuestamente ) la app a la base de datos pero a la hora de registrar a la persona con nombre y contraseña me da el error... Gracias por la ayuda y si pueden explicar las cosas lo más sencilla posible lo agradecería ya que no tengo mucha idea y cualquier sugerencia es bienvenida por supuesto ! ... Infinitas gracias !

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import*
from tkinter import messagebox
import pymysql

def mywindow():
    mywindow = Tk()
   
    mywindow.title("Manu Optimization App")
    mywindow.iconbitmap("foto.ico")
    mywindow.geometry("600x600")
    mywindow.resizable(False,False)

    #Image=PhotoImage(file="Foto.gif")
    #Image=Image.subsample(2,2)
    #Label=Label(Image=Image)
    #Label.pack()# 

    Label(text="Access to the system", bg="navy", fg="white", width="100", height="3", font=("calibri", 15)).pack()
    Label(text="").pack()

    Button(text="Log in", height="3", width="30", command=login).pack()
    Label(text="").pack()

    Button(text="Register", height="3", width="30", command=register).pack()


    mywindow.mainloop()

def login(): 
    global mywindow1
    mywindow1 = Toplevel() 
    mywindow1.geometry("400x250")
    mywindow1.title("Access to the system")
    mywindow1.iconbitmap("foto.ico") 

    Label(mywindow1, text="Please, enter your user and password",bg="navy", fg="white", width="100", height="3", font=("Calibri", 15)).pack()
    Label(mywindow1, text="").pack()


    global nameuser_verify
    global passworduser_verify

    nameuser_verify=StringVar()
    passworduser_verify=StringVar()

    global name_user_entry
    global password_user_entry

    Label(mywindow1, text="User").pack()
    name_user_entry = Entry(mywindow1, textvariable=nameuser_verify)
    name_user_entry.pack()
    Label(mywindow1).pack()

    Label(mywindow1, text="Password").pack()
    password_user_entry = Entry(mywindow1, textvariable=nameuser_verify)
    password_user_entry.pack()
    Label(mywindow1).pack()

    Button(mywindow1, text="Log in").pack()

def register():
    global mywindow2
    mywindow2=Toplevel()
    mywindow2.geometry("400x250")
    mywindow2.title("Register")
    mywindow2.iconbitmap("foto.ico")

    global nameuser_entry
    global password_entry

    nameuser_entry=StringVar()
    password_entry=StringVar()


    Label(mywindow2, text="Please, register a user and password of your\n election for the registration to the system", bg="navy", fg="white", width="100", height="3", font=("Calibri", 15)).pack()
    Label(mywindow2, text="").pack()

    Label(mywindow2, text="User").pack()
    nameuser_entry = Entry(mywindow2)
    nameuser_entry.pack()
    Label(mywindow2).pack()
    
    Label(mywindow2, text="Password").pack()
    password_entry = Entry(mywindow2)
    password_entry.pack()
    Label(mywindow2).pack()


    Button(mywindow2, text="Register", command=insert_data).pack()
    

def insert_data():
    bd=pymysql.connect(
        host="localhost",
        user="root",
        password="",
        db="base de datos"
        )
    fcursor=bd.cursor()

    sql="INSERT INTO login (user, password) VALUES ('{0}','{1}')".format(nameuser_entry.get(), password_entry.get())
        
    try:
        fcursor.execute(sql)
        bd.commit()
        messagebox.showinfo(Message("Succesful registration", title="Warning"))

    except:
        bd.rollback()
        messagebox.showinfo(Message("Not succesful registration", title="Warning"))

    bd.close()
        


mywindow()
```

El error que me sale es el siguiente:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "C:\Users\manuj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py",
> line 1892, in **call**
> return self.func(*args)   File "c:\Users\manuj\OneDrive\Escritorio\Project\Proyect.py", line 111, in
> insert_data
> messagebox.showinfo(Message("Not succesful registration", title="Warning"))   File
> "C:\Users\manuj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py",
> line 3408, in **init**
> Widget.**init**(self, master, 'message', cnf, kw)   File "C:\Users\manuj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py",
> line 2566, in **init**
> BaseWidget.*setup(self, master, cnf)   File "C:\Users\manuj\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter_*init**.py",
> line 2535, in _setup
> self.tk = master.tk AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'tk'

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Por favor, pone un titulo acorde a la pregunta...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Bienvenido a SO ES y a Python Manuel c:

Tu problema se debe a que no estás creando de manera correcta los mensajes de advertencia.
Message es un widget de Tkinter que nada tiene que ver con el tipo de mensaje que buscas.

Para mostrar un messagebox, Cambia esto:

```
messagebox.showinfo(Message("Succesful registration", title="Warning"))
```

Por esto:

```
messagebox.showinfo(message="Succesful registration", title="Warning")
```

Y haz lo mismo con `messagebox.showinfo(Message("Not succesful registration", title="Warning"))`

Mas información sobre los messagebox aquí: https://recursospython.com/guias-y-manuales/cuadros-de-dialogo-messagebox-en-tkinter/

Por cierto, le diste un estilo genial a tu programa!!!

Comment: Joder infinitas gracias !!!!!! solucionado !! menuda tontería era y llevaba 2 días aquí liado y luego era un 'tontería' .. lo que es no saber interpretar los fallos...                  Una última cosa, me gustaría pasar a la siguiente fase de que si un usuario al poner sus datos son correctos como que acceda a la siguiente ventana que ya sería la app donde poner sus datos etc .... podrías darme alguna indicación para saber que tipo de funcione debo buscar?   Muchas gracias una vez más !           Por cierto, no me atribuyas el mérito del estilo ... como dije antes lo copié de un vídeo ;D

Comment: Un placer! Ya veo, la persona del video hizo un muy buen estilo! En realidad lo correcto sería que hicieses otra pregunta, pero estaría basada en recomendaciones y terminaría cerrada. Asi que te lo respondo por aqui ;). Puedes hacer que cuando se presione un boton se abra un Toplevel, que es una ventana hija. En el código que usas se usan Toplevels, más info sobre toplevel aqui: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/tk_toplevel.htm y aqui: https://riptutorial.com/tkinter/example/22130/difference-between-tk-and-toplevel

Comment: Perfecto voy a echarle un ojo y una vez que complete ese paso, ya habré avanzado muchísimo .. infinitas gracias !! por cosas como esta no he perdido la fé en el ser humano ;D

Comment: De nada! Me alegro que no le perdieras la fe a la humanidad :D

Comment: Hola Dante! podría contactarte por privado? Tranquilo, no me quiero aprovechar de ti jajaaj, si te parece, responde a esto, comparto aquí mi email, me escribes y luego borro mi mail... Gracias

Comment: Quizá sea más confiable pasarse al chat de StackOverflow, el problema es que no se como. Si sale lo de no tener charlas extensas en comentarios aprovecho!

Comment: Si no, dale, me arriesgo jajaja

Comment: Ok, pero voy a estar ocupado, asi que mis respuestas pueden ser lentas